# warn message using hazelcast 3.3 during mapstore loadAll

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast v3.3.  The Hazelcast server runs a few map store implementations.  I have sporadically seen the following warning in the logs and need to understand what might be causing this and whether it could lead to data loss in hazelcast.  I have a pretty small cluster at the moment for testing (4VMs running Ubuntu13 - 2GB RAM each).

```
2014-09-14 18:55:21,886 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [main] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.3] While asking 'is-executing': BasicInvocationFuture{invocation=BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:
impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.PartitionIteratingOperation@285583d4, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=10, tryPauseMillis=300, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701}, done=false} java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Call BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.IsStillExecutingOperation@5b202ff, partit
ionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=0, tryPauseMillis=0, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=5000, target=Address[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701} encountered a timeout
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:321)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(BasicInvocationFuture.java:289)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:181)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.isOperationExecuting(BasicInvocationFuture.java:390)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.waitForResponse(BasicInvocationFuture.java:228)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:180)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocationFuture.java:160)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$InvokeOnPartitions.awaitCompletion(BasicOperationService.java:489)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$InvokeOnPartitions.invoke(BasicOperationService.java:458)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$InvokeOnPartitions.access$600(BasicOperationService.java:430)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.invokeOnAllPartitions(BasicOperationService.java:293)
        at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxySupport.size(MapProxySupport.java:616)
        at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.size(MapProxyImpl.java:72)
        at com.akkadian.wildmetrix.StartHcastServer.main(StartHcastServer.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Comment: *"target=Address[192.168.110.153]:5701} encountered a timeout"*. This looks like the most valuable clue as to the cause of this issue.

Comment: that's the local box IP address and the server is already listening on port 5701

Comment: Check garbage collection or any other process slowing down hazelcast from operating normally

Comment: And apparently it's getting timeouts. Which might point to a problem with your network configuration.

Comment: the timeouts occur during processing - the server is already listening on port 5701.  Netstat confirms this.  I can connect via client at a later stage to the server on the ip address and port

Comment: will check garbage collection - there are no other major processes that I am running on the same VM.  I will test with jstatd and jvisualvm or do a GC dump, for now, via top, I can see that memory usage peaks between 70-80% (I know its high which is why I'm thinking it could be GC related)